# Unable to create a patch after modify remote with git set-url

Tags: git

I need to create a patch to submit changes that I made to an application.

What I did so far:

1. `git clone https://github.com/someapp`
2. Modified remote to my bitbucket account.
3. Made modifications and committed everything
4. Pushed all modifications to bitbucket
5. Modified remote back to original repository
6. Attempted creating patch using `git format-patch origin/master --stdout`. This command generates no output

How would I generate a patch in this situation? I can see all commits when I do `git log`

Comment: Rather than modifying the remote URL, I suggest adding two separate remotes so you can track them both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me illustrate what you did. When you cloned the GitHub repo, `origin/master` and the local `master` branch, both point at some commit. Let's call it `A`. Now let's say that after you changed the URL for the `origin` remote, you made one commit `B` and pushed it. Now `origin/master` and `master` both point at commit `B`. When you change the URL of `origin` back to the original GitHub repo, `origin/master` still points at commit `B`. So your attempt to create a patch gives no output because there are no differences between your local `master` and `origin/master`.

Remember that `origin/master` is a "remote tracking branch". While remote tracking branches are intended to reflect the branch on a remote, they are stored locally. When you change the URL of the remote, strange things can happen like what you have seen.

One solution is to add two different remotes to your repository. That way you can track both the `master` of your BitBucket repo and the `master` of the original `GitHub` repo.

Comment: I will add back the original repo and see if I can generate the patch.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, it is very helpful to know about remote tracking branch and how it works. Since I was able to list commits using git log, I created a patch using the command `git format-patch <commit-id>`, using the commit-id of the last commit done in the original GitHub repo.